# Docker copy doesn't seem to work with stopped container and wildcard

Tags: maven, docker

I'm building a maven project inside a docker container:

```
docker run build-image "mvn clean package -f ./pom.xml"
```

The source and workdir in the Dockerfile for "build-image" are located at /src/ (having two subfolders with each containing one submodule with pom.xml, parent pom at /src/pom.xml)

When the build is finished, the container exits. Then, I want to extract the build artifacts:

```
docker cp <container-id>:/src/module1/target/*.war ./
```

I get an error:

```
Error response from daemon: Could not find the file /src/<module1>/target/*.war in container silly_nobel
```

When I specify the file without using the wildcard:

```
docker cp <container-id>:/src/<module1>/target/<module1>##0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.war ./
```

it succeeds..

Is this intended behaviour or a bug? I googled a bit but could not find a similar post with that problem. docker version is `18.02.0-ce, build fc4de44`

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker cp` does not support wildcards at the moment ([github discussion](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7710))

But you can get what you want by using [multi stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds). In multi stage builds you can use `COPY` which allows wildcards.
This is a short example:

```
FROM alpine as builder
RUN touch foo.txt
RUN touch bar.txt


FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /*.txt ./
```

Build an run image:

```
$ docker build -t foobar .
$ docker run foobar ls
bar.txt
bin
dev
etc
foo.txt
...
```